# The correct way to copy data from a sk_buff to a kernel buffer

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel

Can someone give me a full example for copying an entire packet from a sk_buff?  I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
char *pkt = skb_header_pointer(sbuf, 0, sbuf->len, mybuf);
if (mybuf != pkt) {
    memcpy(mybuf, pkt, sbuf->len);
}
```

where `sbuf` is a `struct sk_buff *` and `mybuf` is my own buffer.  For reasons that I don't understand, this function occasionally returns a NULL pointer, indicating something has failed.  What could be the cause?  And what exactly is the best way to copy an entire buffer?

Comment: `skb_header_pointer()` - returns a pointer to either the data in the linear data buffer from skb->data or the pointer to the local data buffer supplied, or NULL if your offset and length were incorrect.

Comment: @askb, yeah I read that somewhere too.  However as you see, I'm passing an offset of 0 and the len is the `len` field, so I don't see how they can be incorrect.